# Tradingview - getting different charts when converting script from Pine v2 to v4

Tags: pine-script

I have been trying for days to understand the mystery of this event. I had a script in v2, which I converted to v4, to be abel to properly test the strategy, but the conversion gave me different lines and different results. Any idea why?

**V2 Script:**

```
//// Calculate EMA values

symbolHigh1 = security(tickerid, tfMA1, high)
symbolLow1  = security(tickerid, tfMA1, low)

symbolHigh2 = security(tickerid, tfMA2, high)
symbolLow2  = security(tickerid, tfMA2, low)

maFibs = exponential1 ? ema(security(tickerid, tfMA1,FValue), maLength1) : sma(security(tickerid, tfMA1,FValue), maLength1)
ma2 = exponential2 ? ema(security(tickerid, tfMA2,ma2src), maLength2) : sma(security(tickerid, tfMA2,ma2src), maLength2)
```

**V4**

```
//// Calculate EMA values

symbolHigh1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, tfMA1, high)
symbolLow1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, tfMA1, low)

symbolHigh2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, tfMA2, high)
symbolLow2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, tfMA2, low)
symbolClose2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, tfMA2, close)

security_1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, tfMA1, FValue)
ema_1 = ema(security_1, maLength1)
security_2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, tfMA1, FValue)
sma_1 = sma(security_2, maLength1)
maFibs = exponential1 ? ema_1 : sma_1
security_3 = security(syminfo.tickerid, tfMA2, ma2src)
ema_2 = ema(security_3, maLength2)
security_4 = security(syminfo.tickerid, tfMA2, ma2src)
sma_2 = sma(security_4, maLength2)
ma2 = exponential2 ? ema_2 : sma_2
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because there were changes to how `security()` works between v2 and v3. It used to use future data by default in v1 and v2, which is no longer the case, as it was producing unrealistic results. [See the usrman here for details](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html#understanding-lookahead).

While the v4 code will not reproduce v2 behavior, that's a good thing.

To be more efficient, your code should look like this. It will use less `security()` calls:

```
//@version=4
study("")

[symbolHigh1, symbolLow1] = security(syminfo.tickerid, tfMA1, [high, low])
[symbolHigh2, symbolLow2, symbolClose2] = security(syminfo.tickerid, tfMA2, [high, low, close])

ema_1S = ema(close, maLength1)
sma_1S = sma(close, maLength1)
[ema_1, sma_1] = security(syminfo.tickerid, tfMA1, [ema_1S, sma_1S])
maFibs = exponential1 ? ema_1 : sma_1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the advise. In the meantime I managed to get the same results as in v2 (my initial goal), by adding lookahead=bamerge.lookahead_on secuirty ().

Comment: Yes, using lookahead on will produce the same, wrong results as in v2. That's the reason why the default value for `lookahead=` was changed in v3: your calculations will be using future data that should not be visible from historical bars, and it will not be able to reproduce that behavior when running in the realtime bar, as there are no future bars to look at there, making your script useless and its calcs misleading. See [How to avoid repainting when using security() - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/).

Answer (score -2):

In the meantime I managed to get the same results as in v2 (my initial goal), by adding `lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on` for the security ().